# Showing a text on page even when scrolling the page to another part

Tags: html, css

I need that some content in my page would keep its position on screen even if the user scrolls the page right.

My HTML is very simple:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Bla</title>     
</head>

<body>
    <!--header start-->
    <header class="header dark-bg"></header>
    <!--header end-->
    <!--sidebar start-->
    <aside>
        <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse ">
            <!-- sidebar menu start-->
            <ul class="sidebar-menu"></ul>
            <!-- sidebar menu end-->
        </div>
    </aside>
    <section id="container" class="">
        <!--main content start-->
        <section id="main-content">
            <section class="wrapper">
                <!--overview start-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <h3 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Dashboard</h3>

                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i><a href="/Home">Home</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Dashboard</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
</body>
```

Take a look at:
    https://jsfiddle.net/2wn8qgyb/

When scrolling right, I expect that the "Dashboard" and "Home / Dashboard" text wouldn't disappear and stand still. I want the user to have an option to click it without scrolling back to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, add an extra classname to this div `<div class="col-lg-12">`, it should now look like `<div class="my-nav-bar col-lg-12">`

After that, just add this to your css file:

```
.my-nav-bar{position:fixed;}
```

**Here is a working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2wn8qgyb/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.page-header {
    position:fixed;
}
.breadcrumb {
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the Position of your div which you don't want to disappear

```
.div
{
position:fixed;
}
```